# Шаблонизатор smarty вывод даты

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код, он берет из базы данных дату и время в unix формате и переводит в нормальную дату. Подскажите пожалуйста, как дополнить код если дата сегодняшняя то он отображает "сегодня" если дата вчерашняя то отображает "вчера" а в остальных случаях пишет просто дату?

```
<div class="date_public">{%$message.date_add|date_format:"%e %B "|replace:'January':'января'|replace:'February':'февраля'|replace:'March':'марта'|replace:'April':'апреля'|replace:'May':'мая'|replace:'June':'июня'|replace:'July':'июля'|replace:'August':'августа'|replace:'September':'сентября'|replace:'October':'октября'|replace:'November':'ноября'|replace:'December':'декабря'%}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу портянку кода сложно назвать удобной в работе. Не уверен, что вопрос еще актуален, но лучше пойти примерно таким путем (код примерный):

```
{if $message.date_add|date_format == $smarty.now|date_format}
     {$txt = "сегодня"}
{elseif $message.date_add|date_format == strtotime('-1 day')|dateformat}
     {$txt = "вчера"}
{else}
     {$m = $message.date_add|date_format:"%m"}
     {$months = ["января", "февраля" .... ]}
     {$txt = ($message.date_format:"%e ".$monts[$m-1])}
{/if}

<div class="date_public">{$txt}</div>
```

у вас, вероятно, старенький smarty, поэтому следует использовать `{assign }` вместо простого присвоения `{$txt = ..}`.

В целом, при неоднократном использовании такие штуки, конечно, стоит выносить  либо в плагин, либо прятать во вложенный шаблон.

В случае плагина, вы эту логику напишите удобным способом на пхп, а потом будете использовать [как и прочие модификаторы,](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/plugins.modifiers.tpl) например, `{$message.date_add|pretty_date}`

Будет как-то так:

```
function smarty_modifier_pretty_date($d){
     if(date("Ymd", $d) == date("Ymd")) return "сегодня";
     ...
}
```